# Django local development, Chrome Blocking requests to local server in frame

Tags: django, google-chrome, iframe

Im developing a web application using the local dev server provided by Django. My local web-app is to be emmbeded in an iframe of a remote site. But when testing Chrome loads the remote site encappsulating webpage (page which is meant to wrap my web-app in an iframe but blocks requests towards my local dev server in the iframe, which makes testing impossible.

I have looked in chrome's console and get the following error:

```
Refused to frame 'https://localhost:8000/' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "child-src 'self' https://* shopify-pos://*". Note that 'frame-src' was not explicitly set, so 'child-src' is used as a fallback.
```

My questions:

1) Why is Chrome blocking requests?

2) Is this error being caused because I am using localhost? and framing work fine on Chrome once I deploy on a production server with domain name?

3) Is there anyway that I may circumvent this error while I am on local host for testing purposes?

Comment: did my answer work

Answer (score 0):

Django uses Clickjacking protection with 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware'.

To allow the site to be embedded in an iframe just erase that middleware from settings.py

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/clickjacking/#clickjacking-prevention

Comment: No, clickjacking middleware is not the culprit in this case, as the request does not even reach my local development web-server. It is blocked within chrome.

Answer (score 0):

try to deactivate CORS protection in Chrome.

this [chrome app](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en) might help.